# Multiple tiles into a Map to a pdf -- using leaflet and jsPdf

Tags: leaflet, jspdf

I am trying to generate a map of multiple tiles and then creating pdf for the same. I am new to leaflet, below is the code to add multple tiles to a map.

```
for (var y = top_tile; y < bottom_tile + 1; y++) {
 for (var x = left_tile; x < right_tile + 1; x++) {
   L.tileLayer(replaceInTemplate({x, y, z: zoom})).addTo(map);
 }
}
function replaceInTemplate(point){
return template.replace('{z}', point.z)
  .replace('{x}', point.x)
  .replace('{y}', point.y);
}
//template is in the form of http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
leafletImage(map, downloadMap);
```

Correct me if I am doing it in wrong way, but somehow I am not able to proceed while converting this map into an image. On map.eachLayer i am unable to move forward, not getting any errors on console as well, Any help is appreciated like if this is the right approach or not. Thanks

Comment: You should use just one instance of `L.TileLayer` - you're currently adding one `L.TileLayer` per *tile*. Have you read the documentation and tutorials about tilelayers?

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation, but I didn't find any restrictions on adding more than one tile layer. Is it not possible to add more than one tile to the map?

Comment: **One** `L.TileLayer` will add **all** the tiles visible in the viewport for a given template. From what I read, you only have one URL template, which means you should add only one tilelayer.